# Master's Method, which Case?

Tags: complexity-theory, big-o, master-theorem

I've been viewing some video lectures from MIT's opencourseware website, and on the third lecture video the lecturer goes over Recursive Matrix Multiplication and comes up with the time complexity being:

`T(n) = Θ(n3)`

It's obvious to me that I really need to review some of my math, but I really don't see the connection from that answer and any one of the cases mentioned for the Master Theorem Method.  I know that the recursive relation is of the form:
`T(n) = a*T(n/b) + f(n)` for n > 1.
With this recursive relation: `a = 8`, `b = 2`, and `f(n) = Θ(n2)`.

So, how did they get `Θ(n3)`?

He mentioned that `log28 = 3`, which makes sense.  But, I just can't figure out which of the three cases that the example recursive relation corresponds to, using the value of `f(n)`.

Since, Case 2 is the only one where `f(n) = Θ(anything)`, then I'm guessing that that's it.  Yet, I guess my problem relates to properties of logarithms or exponents.

If `f(n) = Θ(nlog28 * (log2n)k+1)` then how do you go from having a `Θ(n3)` for `f(n)` to a `Θ(n2)` using case 2?  What is it that I might be missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [the Wiki page on the Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem).

They discuss this very exact situation (a = 8, b=2, f(n) = O(n<sup>2</sup>)) when discussing case 1. (not case 2). Note that if f(n) = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) then f(n) = O(n<sup>2</sup>), so case 1 can be applied.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks.  Before I read your answer, I let the video play on and found that it was from case 1.  Similar to your answer, I figured that they Theta still fit within big Omicron because it has that f(n)<=c*g(n) condition for f(n)=O(n).  So, since Theta(n) sort of implies that f(n) = c*g(n) then it still fits within O(n).